# Join from two table and then join from the resultant to third table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am trying to take `JOIN` from two tables and the resultant table to JOIN with third table but its throwing error, let me know what I am doing wrong here -

```
SELECT e.id as e_id, e.name as e_name, e.artist_id as e_artist_id, e.event_date as e_date, 
        v.id as v_id, v.name as v_name, v.address as v_address, v.latitude as v_latitude, v.longitude as v_longitude 
FROM events e 
LEFT JOIN venues v 
ON e.venue_id = v.id WHERE v.id = 12
LEFT JOIN artists a
ON e.artist_id = a.id
```

Comment: What error is it throwing - because that's like a clue

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN artists a
ON e.artist_id = a.id
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6

Comment: WHERE comes at the end - although if it's a LEFT JOIN then that should be AND

Comment: Though I checked e.artist_id is a column that exists

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `WHERE` clause to an `AND` -

```
SELECT e.id as e_id, e.name as e_name, e.artist_id as e_artist_id, e.event_date as e_date, 
        v.id as v_id, v.name as v_name, v.address as v_address, v.latitude as v_latitude, v.longitude as v_longitude 
FROM events e 
LEFT JOIN venues v 
ON e.venue_id = v.id AND v.id = 12
LEFT JOIN artists a
ON e.artist_id = a.id
```

Comment: This will give unexpected results - the `WHERE v.id = 12` should be in the `ON` condition.

Comment: You cannot put a `WHERE` in an `ON` @Siyual, it causes a syntax error. How does this give unexpected results?

Comment: @JayBlanchard -- this is negating the `outer join`.  I suspect the OP wants something like `left join venues v on e.venue_id = v.id and v.id = 12`...

Comment: I mean, put it as an AND in the ON clause...  Putting it in the WHERE at the end converts the LEFT JOINs to INNER JOINs.

Comment: I have made the change (after testing) @Siyual